# Slightly-off temperatures coming cut of Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am using an [Arduino Due](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue) with a [TMP36](http://www.analog.com/en/mems-sensors/digital-temperature-sensors/tmp36/products/product.html) (for reading temperature). Here is my formula that converts the readings to °F:

```
tempReading = analogRead(tempPin);
voltage = tempReading * 5.0; // Saves the voltage
voltage /= 1024.0; 
tempC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100 ; //Converts to Celsius
tempF = (tempC * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32; //Converts to Fahrenheit
```

In the serial, my Arduino is printing out temperatures from 90-100 °F, and my house is set to about 70 °F. What the problem here be?

Comment: The sensor is not very precise. Don't expect it to be so. Also, it's possible that the supply voltage is not exactly 5V.

Comment: Try to calibrate your 0C-point (0.5) in ice water (wrap the sensor into water-tight plastic), measuring the actual slope (10 mV/C, *100) for the first 40C could also help. Bath thermometer and a little water boiler should suffice.

Comment: thanks ill test that but I have used this fairly accurately with my Arduino Uno

Comment: I just tested the project on my uno and I'm getting about 70*F

Comment: This is probably a better question for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ as soon as though the hardware is no doubt coming into play. Try a post there with both your code and a schematic including the part you're using. Edit to add - the answer below is likely correct though if it's running at 3.3V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue:

"Unlike other Arduino boards, the Arduino Due board runs at 3.3V. The maximum voltage that the I/O pins can tolerate is 3.3V. Providing higher voltages, like 5V to an I/O pin could damage the board."

So likely you should multiply `tempreading` not by 5, but by 3.3.